# how to upload file through activeadmin modal window

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to upload file using modal window,but activeadmin modal module doesn't support .

so I changed source file of activeadmin, actualy `/app/assets/javascripts/active_admin/lib/modal_dialog.js.coffee`

```
ActiveAdmin.modal_dialog = (message, inputs, callback)->
  html = """<form id="dialog_confirm" title="#{message}"><ul>"""
  for name, type of inputs
    if /^(datepicker|checkbox|text)$/.test type
      wrapper = 'input'
    else if type is 'textarea'
      wrapper = 'textarea'
    else if $.isArray type
      [wrapper, elem, opts, type] = ['select', 'option', type, '']
    else
      throw new Error "Unsupported input type: {#{name}: #{type}}"
```

I add change the code  `if /^(datepicker|checkbox|text)$/.test type` to

```
if /^(datepicker|checkbox|text|file)$/.test type
```

then it can show file form, but i can't get the params ,can any one help?

here's my code:

```
$('a.upload').click (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    ActiveAdmin.modal_dialog "send file", choose_file: "file",
      (inputs)=> 
        if inputs.choose_file == ""
          alert "!!！"
        else
          $.post $(@).attr("href"),
            {
              choose_file: inputs.choose_file
            }, (data) ->
              window.location.reload()
```

Answer (score 0):

The form need's to be encoded as multipart:

```
html = """<form id="dialog_confirm" title="#{message}" enctype="multipart/form-data"><ul>"""
```